# Select using partition by mod

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table having more than 5 billion records containing two year data, with definition like:

```
create table test_partition (
  test_data VARCHAR(255),
  create_date DATE
);
```

Most of our queries are for specific month and year, so we decided to partition data with same

```
ALTER TABLE test_partition PARTITION BY HASH(YEAR(create_date) + MONTH(create_date)) PARTITIONS 12;
```

Now I want to retrieve data for Oct, 2018. Following query is working

```
select * from test_partition PARTITION(p0);
```

, but I want to programmatically find partition in which this data reside, something like

```
select * from test_partition PARTITION(p + MOD(2018 + 10, 12));
```

Mysql Version: *5.6.10*

Comment: This is quite interesting. If you get a good answer or find a solution elsewhere I would be glad if you would let me know. From the docs that I read seems you can only access partitions directly by their names however.

Comment: Mysql docs contains information how you can calculate the hash yourself and know in which partitation the data is it algorithm is explained so you can calculated it from the application

Comment: @RaymondNijland please provide me links. I will read them. I am not able to find such

Comment: basically you need to calculate this `SELECT MOD((YEAR('2018-10-12') + MONTH('2018-10-12')), 12);` on 12 partitions and with the used HASH `YEAR(create_date) + MONTH(create_date)` then you would get a valid partition number.. The trick is offcource to do automatic from the application and convert the number into a valid partition name..

Comment: Topicstarter and @apriede here is a quick and dirty [one](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/82efV127exf8dBoEuGDxzN/0) .. it assume the partitions size is the same and you don't give the partitions a name.. Also it works only with only value to select.. The full automatic one that generates custom SQL which can handle more algorithms, multiple values, custom partition naming is way to time consuming to program which involves querying the view `information_schema.partitions`

Comment: ... But MySQL should also do this automatic in the optimizer, it is called [Partition Pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-pruning.html)